# Enable Both X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ip, http-headers, cloudflare

How do I enable both X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For in Nginx? I currently have the following to get real IPs in Docker network.

```
set_real_ip_from  172.18.0.0/32;
real_ip_header    X-Real-IP;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

I would also like to pass real IPs from Cloudflare to Docker containers as well. How do I use both X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For in same configuration, one set of IPs for X-Real-IP and one set of IPs for X-Forwarded-For?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get real IPs from behind CloudFlare, you should instead use their own header, CF-Connecting-IP. You should ignore the other headers if you haven't generated them yourself, as they may be faked by the client.

```
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)ping them (doesn't work):

   ```
   map $remote_addr $real_header {
     default X-Real-IP;
     172.18.0.1 X-Forwarded-For;
   }

   server {
     real_ip_header $real_header;
   }
   ```
2. Try separating those streams into different servers. As per manual real_ip_header can be set per server or location, so you can:

   ```
   server {
     listen :8080;
     real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
     include "/all/other/stuff.conf";
   }

   server {
     listen :8081;
     real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
     include "/all/other/stuff.conf";
   }
   ```
3. Playing with locations will include a lot more syntax sugar to separate them and you will probably need to use if's, but they are [evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). But I think it's quite possible to create two internal locations with a manual internal rewrite between those two. This will be totally hidden from the user.
4. I suppose playing with Lua might also help, but please try previous suggestions first.

Comment: Have you tried this? Many nginx directives do not accept variables.

Comment: Err, you are right. It doesn't give any errors but it just doesn't work. Anyway I'll just add a few other ideas I got. All of them require testing anyway as this situation isn't common.